# Android alert dialog numeric input

Tags: android, android-edittext, numeric, android-alertdialog

Ok guys so I have a alert dialog showing a Edittext asking for password in an activity. everything works fine i also tried using a simple layout file. now the problem is that whenever i try to enforce the numeric input it shows the numeric input but refuses to show any numeric input that is being typed in also in log there blank string show up. It works fine with regular text. But there is also a little weird problem with that if the first charater that u entered is number then it still has the same problem but if u enter some non integer character and then number then it is ok for eg. a5 is good but if u enter 5 then sam problem when u specifically enforce android:inputType="number" 
Now when i try this in regular activity(as a sanity check) it works fine just not in the alertDialog

here is the relevance code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/password_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:text="Password"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:password="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

</LinearLayout>



    public void passwordChecker() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //final EditText input = new EditText(PrivacyActivity.this);
        //input.setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
        //input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        //input.setInputType(InputType.TY);
        //input.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.password, null);

        final EditText mPassword=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.password);

        //final EditText test=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        final EditText input = new EditText(mContext);

        if(true){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(PrivacyActivity.this).setMessage("Enter the password")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //perform deletion from database
                    dialog.cancel();

                    Log.e("error", "Apple "+ mPassword.getText().toString());


                }
            }).setView(input)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    ....
                }
            }).create().show(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: android:inputType="number" try this in your edittext xml and let me know what happen.

Comment: hey like i said i have that bu the input does not show up(numeric keyboard is shown) nor is there as as when i do gettext there is nothing in there

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:capitalize="none"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:password="true"        
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
```

Comment: yeah i read about android:singleLine="true" in some of the forums tried it but that doesn't help either

Answer (score 0):

So my bad took me ages to respond after i found the problem
The problem wasn't either of them above. For some reason I failed to add a code that isn't present above.

so i had over-ridded the alert dialog with one of my function 
as follows. And since i was only listening to the `KEYCODE_DPAD_UP`and`KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER`
it was messing up the numeric keyboard input

```
.setNegativeButton("I don't Agree", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        finish();
                    }
                }).setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                            KeyEvent event) {
                        if (keyCode < KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP || keyCode > KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }).create().show();
```

so for anyone if it helps check what keys u r listening as well.